# Programmatically return to an earlier UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

My iOS app (Xcode 11.5) has a view controller (an instance of class FirstViewController) that presents a UINavigationController.  The UINavigationController pushes two view controllers (instances of classes SecondViewController and ThirdViewController).  The ThirdViewController has a UIButton that successfully takes me back to the FirstViewController:

```
    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        assert(navigationController?.viewControllers.count == 2);
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToFirstViewController", sender: sender);
    }
```

I created this segue with the Interface Builder.  Is there a way I could get back to the FirstViewController purely in Swift, without having to use a segue created with the Interface Builder?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically without storyboards.

```
@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not quite what I want to do.  I want to get all the way back to the FirstViewController, not the SecondViewController.

Comment: In that case, try just calling `dismiss(animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func goBackTo<TargetViewController:UIViewController>(targetViewController:TargetViewController.Type) {
        let allViewController: [UIViewController] = self.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
        for aviewcontroller : UIViewController in allViewController {
            if aviewcontroller.isKind(of: targetViewController) {
                self.popToViewController(aviewcontroller, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you should be able to call it as :

```
   self.navigationController!.goBackTo(targetViewController: MyViewController.self)
```

Comment: Thank you for your ingenious code, but I'm afraid I wasn't clear about my situation.  The FirstViewController I want to go back to is *not* one of the two UIViewControllers in the viewControllers property of the UINavigationController.  The FirstViewController was instantiated before the UINavigationController.  I put an assert into my code to emphasize that only the SecondViewController and the ThirdViewController are in this property.